# How to "Auto-Repair" XML based on XSD?

Tags: java, xml, junit, xsd, mocking

I have a XML and XSD file. the XML file is generated using Java on tomcat/ubuntu platform.

Its used for integration between system. second system is using XSD to validate my XML and it say that my XML is not correct.

I would like to slowly fix the XML file, but there is a time issue. They want my XML to be correct with XSD sooner than ASAP.

Is there any tool/algoritm that can take my XML and the XSD. Add mock fields that are not there.

**What I want:
my not yet correct XML goes into a method and XML correct with XSD is returned.**

It sounds like some testing framework should be able to do that.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a XML schema to fix an XML in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968701/using-a-xml-schema-to-fix-an-xml-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe as `f(invalid XML, target XSD) = valid XML` is virtually impossible to build in a generic fashion, for anything but trivial XML/XSDs... which could be a reason why (at least) I am not aware of any mainstream tool that would do such a thing... (just gave you my short answer to your question).

Given the variety of ways in which the same XML may be described in XSD, and potentially the multitude of ways in which an invalid XML may be made conformant (there are scenarios that strictly speaking are impossible to fix) ... it is more practical to figure out the **pattern** that you need to fix your XMLs (assuming there's consistency in what is wrong with them) and apply those corrections through a custom made script (XSLT could be one, but I've also seen "diffgram"-based approaches, depending on what tools and/or skills you have available).

My own interest in replying here... has to do with the fact that indeed, testing frameworks (we have one, running on Windows only) are typically capable of harvesting test data from various data sources, and create valid XML from it, based on specified XSDs and some sort of mapping metadata. The "mapping metadata" may contain the data needed by the **pattern** I was referring to above...

Configuring such a framework though may take time, depending on complexities in your XML/XSD... The point here, for anything but trivial, there's not much "automagic" going on in testing frameworks either.

(update re: mocking/framework aspect in your comment)

You seem to be trying to fix something that was supposed to fix something else (i.e. mocking). If mocking is what you need, then my approach to mocking is a bit different, if only because I ran into the same problem many years ago (before things such as XQuery or XML databases were even invented). In the simplest setup, data resides in spreadsheets; a proprietary XML Builder `shapes` data into hierarchical sets, which are pulled in by walking through the content model described by (an arbitrary) XSD; data could be pulled from Excel, looked up from external data sources, defaulted, etc. The result can be one or more XML fragments, which then can be transformed using XSLT or COBOL copybooks, and saved as files, or streamed as part of a TCP/IP based mocking framework (for Web Services, IMS transactions, etc.)

This mocking approach that I've described... places "data first" since we realized that same data/test cases can be used to test a Web Service, an IMS transaction, drive UI automated testing... or whatever one runs into in an enterprise environment. "Shaping" data to comply with a particular spec (XSD, COBOL Copybook, CSV, etc.) is "presentation"... hence the separation of concerns. Imagine how easy would be for me to "inject" the fields you seem to be missing and get the new XMLs...

Comment: I disagree, the requirement is just to make XSD pass with keeping current structure. Any XML that makes XSD pass is correct. I could write an app that loops throught all combinations are returns the one that works, but its a big project and I need it for today ;-) Thx for reply

Comment: @IAdapter, you are too vague with details to agree or disagree... on my end. First, you assume that the "current structure" is valid... how would a generic tool know that? Two XMLs may overlap in specific areas, yet different models may lead into, or tail off the same... Generally speaking, there's a big chance for generating all possible combinations to be very expensive (computationally speaking)... If you can share concrete examples, we could have a better conversation... :)

Comment: for example. I have XML <a><b>c</b></a> and schema expects <a><b>c</b><d><e>f</e></d></a>. so my document is missing the d tag. the "very expensive" doesn't matter in this case, because I only need a single right combination that will keep the existing data, for example <a><b>c</b><d><e>testData</e></d></a>

Comment: you are looking for perfect solution and I'm looking for a solution that will just work. now I do it by using string.replace method in java. so I replace("</a>","<d><e>testData</e></d></a>"). but its too brutal for me.

Comment: this is NOT for a production system. this is for a system that now in testing and a client need my XML to be valid, but also doesn't want static, fake XML. So I had to add missing parts using string operations on the output returned by JAXB framework. After I can extract "f" data and send it in XML to my client I will remove the mock. I would prefer for mock to be inteelegent and that it only adds itself when "f" is null. it should know that f is missing based on XSD. Please keep in mind that the "f" data in my case is not a single value, but around 100 values. I had to mock them all.

Comment: I think the project will be very useful for everybody with this kind of integration problems. The client knows that getting this data will take at least a week and puting the mocks takes at least 1 day. Why wast 1 day ? because he needs the XSD valid XML and that can't be by-passed. He's the client. So I wasted 1 day for mocking. He needs them NOW to test his own system. Should I make him and his team wait ?

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting computer science challenge, but difficult to formulate well. In some sense the problem is trivial: if you have a document D that fails to conform to schema S, then you can "repair" D by substituting any document V that is known to conform to S. But that's not useful, what you really want is some document D' that conforms to S and is "similar to" D in some sense; ideally, of all the documents that conform to S, you want to find the one that is closest to D using some suitable metric.

I don't know of any theoretical or practical work on this problem, but it sounds an interesting one to research. Unless you want an answer tomorrow, in which case forget it.

Comment: I think that framework for that would be cool. I did JAXB code geenration to fix my problem, but generic solution would be a very nice idea for an open source project.

Comment: I was even thinking about creating framework like that myself. lets be honest. the goal is to help people with testing integration and giving someone realData + some fakeData is much better than only fakeData or real Data, but not XSD valid, so he can't parse it in the tool of his choice.